# Python and Turkish capitalization

Tags: python, locale, turkish

I have not found a good description on how to handle this problem on **windows** so I am doing it here.

There are two letters in Turkish `ı`(`I`) and `i` (`İ`) which are incorrectly handled by python.

```
>>> [char for char in 'Mayıs']
['M', 'a', 'y', 'i', 's']

>>> 'ı'.upper().lower()
'i'
```

How it should be, given the locale is correct:

```
>>> [char for char in 'Mayıs']
['M', 'a', 'y', 'ı', 's']

>>> 'ı'.upper().lower()
'ı'
```

and

```
>>> 'i'.upper()
'İ'

>>> 'ı'.upper()
'I'
```

I tried `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'Turkish_Turkey.1254')` or even `'ı'.encode('cp857')` but it didn't help.

How do I make python handle these two letters correctly?

Comment: How the heck did you get `['M', 'a', 'y', 'i', 's']` from `[char for char in 'Mayıs']`? I can't reproduce that behaviour on Python 3.8 (`['M', 'a', 'y', 'ı', 's']`) or 2.7 (`['M', 'a', 'y', '\xc4', '\xb1', 's']`). It seems like you're using Python 3, otherwise the `.upper().lower()` would return `'\xc4\xb1'`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python doesn't handle language-specific case mapping without a third-party library. You should use [PyICU](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyICU):

```
>>> from icu import UnicodeString, Locale
>>> tr = Locale("TR")
>>> s = UnicodeString("i")
>>> print(unicode(s.toUpper(tr)))
İ
>>> s = UnicodeString("I")
>>> print(unicode(s.toLower(tr)))
ı
>>>
```

Comment: which version of python do you use to reproduce your results, 3.*? I am getting an error in 2.7.5.

Comment: Post your error maybe, because I run Python 2.7.5 on openSUSE 13.1 RC2.

Comment: moreover, 'toUpper' is not a python string method, where is it coming from?

Comment: cmd.exe is not unicode safe, thats why you are getting an error. Try a better terminal, eg. mintty from cygwin. Also toUpper is a method from UnicodeString class.

Comment: Using cygwin (or any other terminal) is not a workaround, besides I was using spyder IDE.
Anyway, after more than 1 hour of searching and reading forums I could not find the answer how to make it work on windows :(

Comment: It will work with file I/O, printing on the cmd.exe console might not be possible. Just try writing the output into a file.

Answer (score 5):

You can define your own hardcoded function for Turkish character problem.

```
import re

def tr_upper(self):
    self = re.sub(r"i", "İ", self)
    self = re.sub(r"ı", "I", self)
    self = re.sub(r"ç", "Ç", self)
    self = re.sub(r"ş", "Ş", self)
    self = re.sub(r"ü", "Ü", self)
    self = re.sub(r"ğ", "Ğ", self)
    self = self.upper() # for the rest use default upper
    return self


def tr_lower(self):
    self = re.sub(r"İ", "i", self)
    self = re.sub(r"I", "ı", self)
    self = re.sub(r"Ç", "ç", self)
    self = re.sub(r"Ş", "ş", self)
    self = re.sub(r"Ü", "ü", self)
    self = re.sub(r"Ğ", "ğ", self)
    self = self.lower() # for the rest use default lower
    return self
```

regular upper:

```
>>>print("ulvido".upper())
ULVIDO
```

our custom upper:

```
>>>print(tr_upper("ulvido"))
ULVİDO
```

if you need this conversion a lot you can make it .py file. for example: save it as trtextstyle.py and import into your projects.

if trtextstyle.py is same directory with your file:

```
from .trtextstyle import tr_upper, tr_lower
```

hope this helps.

Comment: `replace` might be even cleaner here.

Answer (score 0):

```
def tr_capitalize(param_word):
    word_list = param_word.split(sep=" ")
    new_word = ""
    for word in word_list:
        first_letter = word[0]
        last_part = word[1:]

        first_letter = re.sub(r"i", "İ", first_letter)
        first_letter = re.sub(r"ı", "I", first_letter)
        first_letter = re.sub(r"ç", "Ç", first_letter)
        first_letter = re.sub(r"ş", "Ş", first_letter)
        first_letter = re.sub(r"ü", "Ü", first_letter)
        first_letter = re.sub(r"ğ", "Ğ", first_letter)



        last_part = re.sub(r"İ", "i", last_part)
        last_part = re.sub(r"I", "ı", last_part)
        last_part = re.sub(r"Ç", "ç", last_part)
        last_part = re.sub(r"Ş", "ş", last_part)
        last_part = re.sub(r"Ü", "ü", last_part)
        last_part = re.sub(r"Ğ", "ğ", last_part)


        rebuilt_word = first_letter + last_part
        rebuilt_word = rebuilt_word.capitalize()
        new_word = new_word + " " + rebuilt_word

        
    new_word = new_word.strip()
    return new_word
```

Answer (score 0):

Python can not do locale sensitive Unicode case mapping, at least not without any custom library. The manual states it exactly:

> There is no way to perform case conversions and character classifications according to the locale.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/locale.html

You should write your custom function (like ulvido and hasan içli suggested)  or use for example PyICU (like ismail) which is not very pythonic. And of course do not use cmd.exe for anything Unicode related.

Python 3 example:

```py
import locale
import unicodedata

from icu import UnicodeString, Locale  # pip install pyicu


lowercase_i_w_dot = "i"
uppercase_i_wo_dot = "I"

# Set locale for ICU
tr = Locale("TR")

# ICU uppercasing
uppercase_i_w_dot = str(UnicodeString(lowercase_i_w_dot).toUpper(tr))
unicodedata.name(uppercase_i_w_dot)  # 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE'

# ICU lowercasing
lowercase_i_wo_dot = str(UnicodeString(uppercase_i_wo_dot).toLower(tr))
unicodedata.name(lowercase_i_wo_dot)  # 'LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I'

# Even if doing
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'tr_TR.UTF-8')

# Normal uppercasing
unicodedata.name(lowercase_i_w_dot.upper())  # 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I'

# Normal lowercasing
unicodedata.name(uppercase_i_wo_dot.lower())  # 'LATIN SMALL LETTER I'
```